# Using result of Solve as plot parameter

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Recently I have faced a problem I would appreciate it, if you helped me
I have the following code in Mathematica
I want to plot a function let say `z * 10 * t` where `z` is one of the roots of `x^2 == 1`.

```
Sol = Solve[x^2 == 1, x];
Plot[z*10*t /. z /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

But it fails, could you please tell me why?

Comment: `sol = Solve[x^2 == 1, x]; Plot[x*10*t /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 10}]`. I'm assuming you want `x` to be `z`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sol = Solve[x^2 == 1, x];
With[{z = sol[[1, 1, 2]]}, Plot[z*10*t, {t, 0, 10}]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, plotting for each solution:

```
Sol = Solve[x^2 == 1, x];
Plot[Evaluate[z*10*t /. z -> Flatten@Sol[[;; , ;; , 2]]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]